# Statsmodels Robust Linear Regression; is F-test Valid?

Tags: p-value, linear-model, f-test, statsmodels

For the sm.OLS() models, there is a provided Ftest and a p value inside the .summary() function.

for [Robust Linear Regression](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/rlm.html) sm.RLM() there is no such value in the .summary() function
yet there is a .f_test() function in the methods, so following the .[Example](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.f_test.html) on OLS, i performed an F test, to tests that each coefficient is jointly statistically significantly different from zero for my RLM:

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

feat_d # my feature data of shape (N Samples,1)
#constructed polynimial features with sklearn
polynomial_features= PolynomialFeatures(degree=4) # varying degrees are tryed out
feat_for_fit = polynomial_features.fit_transform(feat_d)
est = sm.RLM(y, feat_for_fit).fit()
A = np.identity(len(est.params))
A = A[1:,:]
Ftest = est.f_test(A)
>>> overflow encountered in multiply
>>> covariance of constraints does not have full rank. The number of constraints is 5, but rank is 3

print(Ftest)
>>> <F test: F=array([[4549.62604321]]), p=0.0, df_denom=1.52e+04, df_num=8>
```

The F test Values are all very large(positive and negative) and the p values are all either 0.0 or 1 depending on polynomial degree. I am very skeptical if this is even the right test. But from my understanding of multiple linear regression and [This Site's](https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/7-3-joint-hypothesis-testing-using-the-f-statistic.html), it is correct to use this test.

This is the example from statsmodels, just with RLM instead of OLS. It does not display the messages while performing the F test. This might be the cause.

```py
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
data = sm.datasets.longley.load(as_pandas=False)
data.exog = sm.add_constant(data.exog)
results = sm.RLM(data.endog, data.exog).fit()
A = np.identity(len(results.params))
A = A[1:,:]
print(results.f_test(A))
>>> <F test: F=array([[354.23793113]]), p=3.6439243341019165e-10, df_denom=9, df_num=6>
```

additional information: I have a dataset with 21 k Samples and Fit models with 16k, the rest is for validation.

Some Plots:

[image: R2 Positive, negative F-test, p = 1]
[image: R2 Positive, positive F-test, p = 0.0000000]

Answer (score 1):

The occurring error of p-value = 1 and ´>>> overflow encountered in multiply´ was evadable by studentizing the feature and target Data
as suggestet[by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46184092/9447180)